# Pyspark: How to filter a Dataframe on a MapType column? (as in the style of isin() )

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

When i want to filter a Dataframe on a MapType column in the style of a `isin()`, what would be the best strategy?

So basically I want to get all rows of a dataframe where the contents of a MapType column match one of the entries in a list of MapType-"instances". Could also be a join on that column, but all the methods I tried so far fail because `EqualTo does not support ordering on type map`.

Apart from the straight forward methods of using isin() or join() I also came up with the idea to dump the map to json using `to_json()` and then filter on the Json strings, but this seems to randomly order the keys so that this string comparison isn't reliable either?

Is there something easy that I'm missing? How would you recommend to tackle this?

Example df:

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+
|key |metric                                                   |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+
|123k|Map(metric1 -> 1.3, metric2 -> 6.3, metric3 -> 7.6)      |
|d23d|Map(metric1 -> 1.5, metric2 -> 2.0, metric3 -> 2.2)      |
|as3d|Map(metric1 -> 2.2, metric2 -> 4.3, metric3 -> 9.0)      |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

filter ( pseudocode ):

```
df.where(metric.isin([
 Map(metric1 -> 1.3, metric2 -> 6.3, metric3 -> 7.6),
 Map(metric1 -> 1.5, metric2 -> 2.0, metric3 -> 2.2)
])
```

Desired output:

```
----+---------------------------------------------------------+
|key |metric                                                   |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+
|123k|Map(metric1 -> 1.3, metric2 -> 6.3, metric3 -> 7.6)      |
|d23d|Map(metric1 -> 1.5, metric2 -> 2.0, metric3 -> 2.2)      |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: what match means? match on the key, or match on the value? or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing 2 map columns in spark is not that obvious. For each key in the first map you need to check if you have the same value in the second one. Same for keys.

It might be more simple to use UDF, as in Python you can check dict equality :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

map_equals = F.udf(lambda x, y: x == y, BooleanType())

# create map1 literal to filter with
map1 = F.create_map(*[
    F.lit(x) for x in chain(*{"metric1": 1.3, "metric2": 6.3, "metric3": 7.6}.items())
])

df1 = df.filter(map_equals("metric", map1))

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+----+------------------------------------------------+
#|key |metric                                          |
#+----+------------------------------------------------+
#|123k|[metric1 -> 1.3, metric2 -> 6.3, metric3 -> 7.6]|
#+----+------------------------------------------------+
```

---

Another way is to add the map literals you want to filter with as columns and check if for every key in `metric` you get the same value from that literal map.

Here's an example using `transfrom` on map keys array with `array_min` to create filter expression. (if `array_min` returns true this means all the values are equal):

```
filter_map_literal = F.create_map(*[
    F.lit(x) for x in chain(*{"metric1": 1.3, "metric2": 6.3, "metric3": 7.6}.items())
])

df1 = df.withColumn("filter_map", filter_map_literal).filter(
    F.array_min(F.expr("""transform(map_keys(metric),
                           x -> if(filter_map[x] = metric[x], true, false)
                    )""")
                )
).drop("filter_map")
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant way to compare equality of maps: you can collect the map keys, compare the value of each key in both maps, and make sure that all the values are the same. I guess it's better to construct a filter df, and do a semi join, rather than passing them using `isin`:

Sample df and filter df:

```
df.show(truncate=False)
+----+------------------------------------------------+
|key |metric                                          |
+----+------------------------------------------------+
|123k|[metric1 -> 1.3, metric2 -> 6.3, metric3 -> 7.6]|
|d23d|[metric1 -> 1.5, metric2 -> 2.0, metric3 -> 2.2]|
|as3d|[metric1 -> 2.2, metric2 -> 4.3, metric3 -> 9.0]|
+----+------------------------------------------------+

filter_df = df.select('metric').limit(2)
filter_df.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------------+
|metric                                          |
+------------------------------------------------+
|[metric1 -> 1.3, metric2 -> 6.3, metric3 -> 7.6]|
|[metric1 -> 1.5, metric2 -> 2.0, metric3 -> 2.2]|
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Filtering method:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df.alias('df').join(
    filter_df.alias('filter_df'),
    F.expr("""
        aggregate(
            transform(
                concat(map_keys(df.metric), map_keys(filter_df.metric)),
                x -> filter_df.metric[x] = df.metric[x]
            ),
            true,
            (acc, x) -> acc and x
        )"""),
     'left_semi'
)

result.show(truncate=False)
+----+------------------------------------------------+
|key |metric                                          |
+----+------------------------------------------------+
|123k|[metric1 -> 1.3, metric2 -> 6.3, metric3 -> 7.6]|
|d23d|[metric1 -> 1.5, metric2 -> 2.0, metric3 -> 2.2]|
+----+------------------------------------------------+
```